# Как получить сообщения сообщества при помощи yt-dlp?

Tags: python, yt-dlp

Не могу найти в документации каким образом можно получить сообщения сообщества, примерно в том же формате, что и видео (то есть словарь, в котором есть условно содержание, дата опубликования и т.п.)

Comment: `--get-comments` не подходит?

Comment: не, это не то: ``Retrieve video comments to be placed in the infojson. The comments are fetched even without this option if the extraction is known to be quick (Alias: --get-comments)`` (из документации)